# parent_of prolog

Tags: prolog, family-tree

I am new to prolog and would like to have some advice.

I have some facts:

```
male(tom).
male(james).
male(john).
female(elly).
female(joanne).
female(evonne).
brother(john,tom).
brother(john,joanne).
sister(elly,joanne).
parent_of(evonne,john).
parent_of(james,john).
```

Is is possible to define a `parent_of` rule without using `sister` and `brother`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog Parent relation using only brother and sister rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714834/prolog-parent-relation-using-only-brother-and-sister-rules)

Comment: that one is use sister and brother to define parent of i dont want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should have some `parent_of` facts as the core of parental relation. then you can expand this relation by attaching someone to a one of the facts as a child or as a parent. so you need to use a `siblings/2` rule if you want to attach a child, or a `couples/2` rule if you want to attach a parent.

```
%if you want to attach a child by 'siblings' relation
parent_of_rule(X, Y) :-
        parent_of(X, Z),
        siblings(Z, Y).
```

```
%if you want to attach a parrent by 'couples' relation
parent_of_rule(X, Y) :-
        parent_of(Z, Y),
        couples(X, Z).
```

i don't think it's possible to have a `parent_of_rule` rule without the use of a third party relation.

Comment: i have define the rules of siblings ,spouse, son, daughter,father and mother. However i encounter a infinite loop between them. I will go try this and see.

Comment: you're right. easily you can change the name of the rule to allow transitivity and avoid infinite loop. you can also use a cut.